# How do I track down the cause of 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64'?

Tags: swift, xcode, linker, linker-errors

This is a little embarrassing, but I'm getting several self-inflicted errors after, I believe, fat-fingering my settings. I was working away and hit a strange combination of keys and the next thing I knew I was in my project settings. I didn't think much of it and so I went on working and the next time I tried to build my project, I started getting `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`, `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`, and `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` errors:

[image]

I've looked at a lot of threads, many of which blame third-party libraries which I'm not using in my project. I've tried many of the suggested remedies like:

1. cleaned my project
2. deleted my Derived Data folder
3. Made sure all of my project files had their Target Membership set to my project
4. I **would** try to `use -v to see invocation` but I'm a noob and I don't know where I would do that
5. Checked many of my settings as suggested in a lot of the threads I've found

I don't want to try other things blindly because I'm afraid I'll make it worse. From the screenshot above, can anybody help me decipher what it says and give me a little guidance on what to try next?